# recycler view not showing anything...how to solve it?

Tags: android

`RecyclerView` not showing anything

This is my `oncreate view`

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_money_transfer_customers, null);

    validate = (Button)v.findViewById(R.id.validate);
    delete = (Button)v.findViewById(R.id.delete);
    reinitiate = (Button)v.findViewById(R.id.reinitiate);
    transfer = (Button)v.findViewById(R.id.transfer);

    progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(getContext());
    progressDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
    progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
    progressDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);

    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) v.findViewById(R.id.transactio_rep_recyclerView);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);

    userValidate = (UserValidate)getArguments().getSerializable("UserValidate");

    new ValidateUser().execute();

    return v;
}
```

this is how i set adapter to recycler view......

```
 adapter = new MoneyTransferCustomersCardAdapter(beneficiaryDetailsList,this);
                recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

this is my adapter class....

```
   public class MoneyTransferCustomersCardAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MoneyTransferCustomersCardAdapter.ViewHolder>{

    MoneyTransferCustomersCardAdapter moneyTransferCustomersCardAdapter = this;

    List<BeneficiaryDetails> beneficiaryDetailsList;

    public MoneyTransferCustomersCardAdapter(List<BeneficiaryDetails> beneficiaryDetailsList, MoneyTransferCustomersFragment.ValidateUser MoneyTransferCardAdapter) {
        super();
        this.beneficiaryDetailsList = beneficiaryDetailsList;
    }

    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.money_transfer_customers_card, parent, false);
        ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(v);

        final Animation anim_record_item = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(parent.getContext(), R.anim.swipe_down);
        viewHolder.itemView.startAnimation(anim_record_item);

        return viewHolder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        try{

            BeneficiaryDetails bd = beneficiaryDetailsList.get(position);
            holder.vtxtName.setText(bd.getBeneficiaryName());
            holder.vtxtAccount.setText(bd.getAccountNumber());
            holder.vtxtIfsc.setText(bd.getIFSC());

        }catch(Exception e){
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return 0;
    }

    class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        public TextView vtxtName;
        public TextView vtxtAccount;
        public TextView vtxtIfsc;

        public CardView cardViewTxCardItem;

        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            final View view = itemView;

            vtxtName = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.name);
            vtxtAccount = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.account);
            vtxtIfsc = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.ifsc);
            cardViewTxCardItem = (CardView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.cardview_tx_card_item);

        }
    }
}
```

above code working normallly....but recycler view not showing anything.....

```
Log RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout
```

Comment: where are placed you setting adapter code? post entire class please

Comment: try this `public int getItemCount() { return beneficiaryDetailsList.size() ; }` and make sure you have the data when you set the adapter

Comment: its working ...!!! thank you @Pavneet

Comment: @suraj i am glad that i could help , happy coding

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to `return` the size of data in you adapter instead of `0` otherwise `Adpater` will always assume that there is no data to display.

```
   @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return beneficiaryDetailsList.size();
               //^^^^^^^ return list size , actual length of data to be displayed
    }
```